# How do I make a large number of concurrent HTTPS requests robustly in Clojure (/Java)

Tags: networking, asynchronous, clojure, core.async, http-kit

I have a stream of inputs and I want to make 2 `HTTPS` network requests for each before passing the result on to another part of the program. The typical throughput is 50 per second.

```
for each input:
    HTTP request A
    HTTP request B
    pass event on with (A.body and B.body)
```

I am using the [`http-kit`](http://www.http-kit.org/client.html) client, which is asynchronous by default. It returns a promise, and can also take a callback. Http-kit uses Java NIO (see [here](https://github.com/http-kit/http-kit/blob/0867a772e66a1b183c0ef7b3890e26ae1bef1f9d/src/org/httpkit/client.clj#L154) and [here](https://github.com/http-kit/http-kit/blob/0867a772e66a1b183c0ef7b3890e26ae1bef1f9d/src/java/org/httpkit/client/HttpClient.java#L214))

The speed of requests coming in, combined with the time to make a request, is high enough that this needs to be done asynchronously.

I've tried 3 approaches:

1. When an event comes in, put it on a channel. A number of `go` routines pulling off the channel. Each make requests that 'block' the goblock by `deref`ing promises from HTTP requests. This doesn't work because I don't think that the promise plays well with threads.
2. When an event comes in, immediately start a `future`, which 'blocks' on the async promises. This results in **very** high CPU usage. Plus starvation of network resources somehow.
3. When an event comes in, trigger the `http-kit` request immediately for request A, passing in a callback which makes request B, passing a callback that passes the event on. This lead to an out of memory error after a few hours.

These all work and handle the capacity for a while. They all crash eventually. The most recent crash, after about 12 hours:

```
Mar 10, 2016 2:05:59 AM com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector run
WARNING: com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@1bc8a7f5 -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating emergency threads for unassigned pending
 tasks!
Mar 10, 2016 3:38:38 AM com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector run
WARNING: com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@1bc8a7f5 -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete Status:
        Managed Threads: 3
        Active Threads: 1
        Active Tasks:
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1DestroyResourceTask@65d8b232 (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0)
        Pending Tasks:
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@359acb0d
Pool thread stack traces:
        Thread[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0,5,main]
                com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:560)
        Thread[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1,5,main]
                java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
                com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:534)
        Thread[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2,5,main]
                java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
                com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:534)


Thu Mar 10 04:38:34 UTC 2016 [client-loop] ERROR - select exception, should not happen
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.<init>(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:77)
        at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.<init>(OutputRecord.java:76)
        at sun.security.ssl.EngineOutputRecord.<init>(EngineOutputRecord.java:65)
        at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.<init>(HandshakeOutStream.java:63)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.activate(Handshaker.java:514)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.kickstartHandshake(SSLEngineImpl.java:717)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.beginHandshake(SSLEngineImpl.java:743)
        at org.httpkit.client.HttpClient.finishConnect(HttpClient.java:310)
        at org.httpkit.client.HttpClient.run(HttpClient.java:375)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Mar 10, 2016 4:56:34 AM baleen.events invoke
SEVERE: Thread error: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Mar 10, 2016 5:00:43 AM baleen.events invoke
SEVERE: Thread error: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Mar 10, 2016 4:58:25 AM baleen.events invoke
SEVERE: Thread error: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I don't know what the cause of failure is. It might be that there are too many closures being held on to, or gradual resource leakage, or thread starvation.

*Questions*

1. Does making 50 HTTP requests per second, each of which might take 200ms, meaning that there might be 100 requests in flight at any given time, sound like an excessive burden?
2. How do I do this in a way that handles the throughput and is robust?

**EDIT**

YourKit profiler tells me that I have about 2GB of `char[]`s via `org.httpkit.client.Handler`s via `java.util.concurrent.FutureTask`s which suggests that references to old Handlers (i.e. requests) are being retained somehow. The whole reason for trying to use callbacks was to avoid this (although they might somehow be caught up in closures)

Comment: OutOfMemoryError indicates that there is a problem holding on to memory... but we can't help without seeing your code or writing a complete solution from scratch. I'd look for holding onto the head of an infinite sequence, or not cleaning up resources such as connections.

Comment: I wondered if it might be buffers being retained, but as far as I can tell the garbage collection should handle freeing memory / external buffers that e.g. NIO had allocated. What happens downstream is pretty much just a database insert and an insertion onto a channel.

Comment: I thought about posting the code but it's quite involved and would take about a day to know if I'd replicated the problem in a simplified version.

Comment: Could it be that the events are not being drained at the receiver fast enough? One thing you can do is analyze a heap dump to see where the memory is being taken up.

Comment: I have been poking around with YourKit, see the edit. Still trying to work out how references are being retained.

Comment: Are you sure they aren't live connections? You might want to log a count of how many connections are live at any given time?

Comment: In previous testing I've put the number of requests in flight at a lowish number (10 or so) and it seems to remain steady. Meanwhile, heap slowly creeps up (and won't be force-gd'd). I haven't profiled it for a long period.

Comment: Ah ok cool. If there are connection objects, consider using `with-open` around them to make sure they get closed after you are done with them.

Comment: @Joe Are you sure you are not retaining references to your handler functions? Are `FutureTask`s the only paths to GC roots? If yes, what keeps references to those `FutureTask`s? And in general: did you try http://www.http-kit.org/client.html#combined? Is the memory leak the only reason such a solution doesn't work for you?

Comment: Thanks @PiotrekBzdyl. I used the method you linked to in my approach #1 and #2. I think I must somehow be holding onto references but I can't see how. I'm working on a simple reproduction.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Does making 50 HTTP requests per second, each of which might take 200ms, meaning that there might be 100 requests in flight at any given time, sound like an excessive burden?

This is definitely *not* excessive on modern hardware.

> 2. How do I do this in a way that handles the throughput and is robust?

You can combine core.async pipelines and http-kit's callbacks to achieve this. You don't really need to create a `go` routine for each request (although that shouldn't hurt), because you can use async `put!` from the http-kit callback.

Use bounded buffers for each step of the pipeline to limit the number of active connections, which will (at least) be constrained by the number of ephemeral TCP ports available on your system.

Here's an example of a small program that does something similar to what you described. It reads "events" from a channel—in this case, each event is the ID "1"—and looks up those IDs on an HTTP service. It takes the response from that first call, looks up the JSON key `"next"` and enqueues that as the URL for step 2. Finally, when this lookup is complete it adds an event to the `out` channel which a `go` routine monitors to report statistics.

```
(ns concur-req.core
  (require [clojure.core.async :as async]
           [cheshire.core :refer [decode]]
           [org.httpkit.client :as http]))

(defn url-of
  [id]
  ;; this service responds within 100-200ms
  (str "http://localhost:28080/" id ".json"))

(defn retrieve-json-async
  [url c]
  (http/get url nil
            (fn [{body :body status :status :as resp}]
              (if (= 200 status)
                (async/put! c (decode body true))
                (println "ERROR:" resp))
              (async/close! c))))

(defn run [parallelism stop-chan]
  (let [;; allocate half of the parallelism to each step
        step1-n    (int (max (/ parallelism 2) 1))
        step2-n    step1-n
        ;; buffer to take ids, transform them into urls
        step1-chan (async/chan step1-n (map url-of))
        ;; buffer for result of pulling urls from step1, xform by extracting :next url
        step2-chan (async/chan step2-n (map :next))
        ;; buffer to count completed results
        out-chan   (async/chan 1 (map (constantly 1)))
        ;; for delivering the final result
        final-chan (async/chan)
        start-time (System/currentTimeMillis)]

    ;; process URLs from step1 and put the result in step2
    (async/pipeline-async step1-n step2-chan retrieve-json-async step1-chan)
    ;; process URLs from step2 and put the result in out
    (async/pipeline-async step2-n out-chan retrieve-json-async step2-chan)

    ;; keep the input channel full until stop-chan is closed.
    (async/go-loop []
      (let [[v c] (async/alts! [stop-chan [step1-chan "1"]])]
        (if (= c stop-chan)
          (async/close! step1-chan)
          (recur))))

    ;; count messages on out-chan until the pipeline is closed, printing
    ;; status message every second
    (async/go-loop [status-timer (async/timeout 1000) subt 0 accu 0]
      (let [[v c] (async/alts! [status-timer out-chan])]
        (cond (= c status-timer)
              (do (println subt "records...")
                  (recur (async/timeout 1000) 0 (+ subt accu)))

              (nil? v)
              (async/>! final-chan (+ subt accu))

              :else
              (recur status-timer (+ v subt) accu))))

    ;; block until done, then emit final report.
    (let [final-total (async/<!! final-chan)
          elapsed-ms  (- (System/currentTimeMillis) start-time)
          elapsed-s   (/ elapsed-ms 1000.0)]
      (print (format "Processed %d records with parallelism %d in %.3f seconds (%d/sec)\n"
                     final-total parallelism elapsed-s
                     (int (/ final-total elapsed-s)))))))

(defn run-for
  [seconds parallelism]
  (let [stop-chan (async/chan)]
    (future
      (Thread/sleep (* seconds 1000))
      (async/close! stop-chan))
    (run parallelism stop-chan)))

(do
  ;; Warm up the connection pool, avoid somaxconn problems...
  (doseq [p (map #(* 20 (inc %)) (range 25))]
    (run-for 1 p))
  (run-for (* 60 60 6) 500))
```

To test this, I set up an HTTP service that responds only after sleeping a random time between 100-200ms. Then I ran this program for 6 hours on my Macbook Pro.

With parallelism set to 500, I got 1155 completed transactions per second on average (2310 completed HTTP requests per second). I'm sure this could be much higher with some tuning (and especially by moving the HTTP service onto a different machine). The JVM memory creeped up to 1.5 GB within the first 30 minutes and then maintained that size. I'm using Oracle's 64-bit 1.8 JVM.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to your method A (`deref`ing the HTTP-kit returned futures inside a go-block) might be a possibility, just doing so in a way that doesn't cause blocking the core.async handler threads on the future, which you can do by combining httpkit's callbacks and core.async:

```
(defn handle-event
 "Return a core.async channel that will contain the result of making both HTTP call A and B."
  [event-data]
  (let [event-a-chan (clojure.core.async/chan)
        event-b-chan (clojure.core.async/chan)
        return-chan (clojure.core.async/chan)]
    (org.httpkit.client/request "https://event-a-call"
                                {:method :get :params {"param1-k" "param1-v"}}
                                (fn [resp]
                                  (clojure.core.async/put! event-a-chan resp)))
    (org.httpkit.client/request "https://event-b-call"
                                {:method :get :params {"param1-k" "param1-v"}}
                                (fn [resp]
                                  (clojure.core.async/put! event-b-chan resp)))
    (clojure.core.async/go
      (clojure.core.async/>! return-chan {:event-a-response (clojure.core.async/<! event-a-chan)
                                          :event-b-response (clojure.core.async/<! event-b-chan)}))
    return-chan))
```